# multiple opencart login/logout issue

Tags: opencart

I have 2 stores built in OpenCart. I have built a store and put it on domain 1, then copied everything from store 1 to store 2. When I login to store 1's admin, store 2's admin gets logged out.

Problem found :
`$this->session->data['token']` - here the values of store 2 gets changed when logged in to store 1.

Is there any way to overcome this?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution would be to have two separate users. Any user should not be using two logins the same on two separate stores at once. If you're really want to stop it, you can find this code in your `/admin/controller/common/home.php`

```
 || ($this->request->get['token'] != $this->session->data['token'])
```

And remove it but I would advise against it since that will stop any token checking which is there to stop CSRF attacks on your site